# How to create upvote/downvote component in React?

Tags: reactjs

So I would like to create a upvote/downvote component within my React application. Below is a work in progress in trying to do so. I currently have two buttons but I would like to have one button that upvotes the first time it is clicked and then downvotes the next time that same button is click. Please let me know what changes I would need to make in order to accomplish this.

```
import React from 'react';

class Upvote extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            count: 0
        }
    }

    increment = () => {

        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1
        })
    }

    decrement = () => {

        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count - 1
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.increment}>
                    +
                </button>
                <span>{this.state.count}</span>
                <button onClick={this.decrement}>
                    -
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Upvote;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt could be just to guard the individual buttons based on the state of the count like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.count < 1 && <button onClick={this.increment}>
        +
      </button>}
      <span>{this.state.count}</span>
      {this.state.count > -1 && <button onClick={this.decrement}>
        -
      </button>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Of course, if your count ends up being dependent on other users voting as well, you might want to get more sophisticated and add the ability to track the current user's vote rather than the overall vote count.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the following code should do the trick:

```
import React from 'react';

class Upvote extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            count: 0,
            addend: 0 // either 1, 0, or -1
        }
    }

    toggleIncrement = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            addend: prevState.addend === 1 ? 0 : 1
        }))
    }

    toggleDecrement = () => {

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            addend: prevState.addend === -1 ? 0 : -1
        }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.toggleIncrement}>
                    +
                </button>
                <span>{this.state.count + this.state.addend}</span>
                <button onClick={this.toggleDecrement}>
                    -
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Upvote;
```

Here's a list of what I did:

1. Use a separate state variable, named addend, which tracks the user's current vote.
2. Use [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to toggle or replace the addend value depending on whether the other button was pressed.

If the user upvotes, you want them to immediately be able to override that with a downvote. With this setup, the following interaction flows work as expected:

- User presses upvote -> addend increments to 1 -> user presses upvote -> addend goes back to 0
- User presses upvote -> addend increments to 1 -> user presses downvote -> addend goes to -1

Answer (score 0):

By storing the first vote in the state, and then decrement with the same button:

```
import React from 'react';

class Upvote extends React.Component {

   constructor(props){
       super(props)
       this.state = {
           count: 0,
           hasUpvoted: false,
       }
   }

   increment = () => {

     this.setState({
         count: this.state.count + 1,
         hasVoted: true
     })
   }

   decrement = () => {

      this.setState({
        count: this.state.count - 1
      })
   }

   render() {
     return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={ this.state.hasVoted ? this.decrement: this.increment}>
                +
            </button>
            <span>{this.state.count}</span>
            <button onClick={this.decrement}>
                -
            </button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Upvote;
```